# Tomcat session prolongation exclusion

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Does it have some mechanism to exclude URL where user can prolong session??
I have a JS monitoring script which send requests during inactivity, mouse moving and etc - this cause the session prolongation.

Comment: what do you do with those "ping" requests on the server - do you need access to the session?

Comment: @wero i need: it monitors the user's activity. And i can't remove JSESSIONID header from request.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your monitoring script send the request during the inactivity to extend the session of the user.

If you would not use the monitoring script then Your user would be logout from the application due to session timeout.

You can use the session time feature of the Web-Application.

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>

The number in session-timeout tag is in minutes. To make it unlimited or no time out in Tomcat, simply set the number to -1 and restart your Tomcat.
```